# nginx seems to get recompiled on its own

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rtmp

I have a server on DigitalOcean based on Ubuntu 20.04 and running nginx 1.18. I compiled it with rtmp. I was able to stream, publish and play as well. I used OBS studio for streaming.
The next day when I try to publish, OBS reported connection error.

When I logged into the server, I could see that nginx was not running.

I tried executing nginx -t on the command line and I got this error:
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "rtmp" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:36
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

I tried nginx -V and there I noticed that the configure arguments were very different from what I had used to install nginx + rtmp. There is no mention of rtmp in the output.

Suspecting some foul play, we created another droplet on DO. It worked well. But the very next day, I see the same issue.

What could have gone wrong? What logs can I check to see if someone is hacking the server?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the reason why this was happening. I had to uninstall unattended-upgrades package.
This package was responsible for the issue as it would break my custom configured nginx install on update.